# How to enable auto formatting for specific subfolders only?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, formatting, autoformatting, vs-code-settings

When working on a team project with various preferences, how can one enable auto formatting on a specific folder (not file type) only?

For example:

```
"[folder:my-subfolder/sub-folder-2]":
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
}
```

I've read that it's not possible to add a separate `settings.json` per folder. Is there another way to do this? Or is it not possible at this moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of this writing, this has been declared out of scope (as a core VS Code feature) twice now.

1. [Setting to exclude file patterns from editor.formatOnSave #147677](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/147677)
2. [Exclude files or directories from editor.formatOnSave #176946](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/176946)

If you think that the feature-request is crucial, share your use-case in #176946 (please do so politely and with humility if you can).